# Octopus - Rollback to previous version

Tags: selenium, octopus-deploy

I have two steps in my Octopus deploy process. 1st step deploys my web application to the development environment and the 2nd step runs selenium tests against the dev environment (on new changes).

Currently, Octopus doesn't rollback the web application to previous version (Step 1) if one of the selenium tests fails.

I wanted to know if there is some setting in Octopus to do that.

Comment: I'd personally rather change so my deployment doesn't rely on a step with tests, but my selenium tests would have a deployment as first step of it. Anyways there is a [rollback section in Octopus blog](https://octopus.com/blog/rollback)

Comment: Consider the use of a `DeployFailed.<ext>` file: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Custom+scripts . https://octopus.com/blog/deployfailed